# Serialization exception in HazelCast 3.5 with Scala

Tags: scala, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast 3.5 with scala 
i have a case class Abc i am trying to store object of my class in hazelcast from my client  but it gives me some serialization exception

here is my class

```
 @SerialVersionUID(1)
    case class Abc( id : Int ,name : String , subjectCode : MutableList[Int]) extends Serialable
```

when i run the client code it gives me following exception

```
18:33:43.274 [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.partition-operation.thread-1] ERROR c.h.map.impl.operation.PutOperation - [192.168.15.20]:5701 [dev] [3.5] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DefaultSerializers$ObjectSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:201) ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:41) ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:276) ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.mapstore.AbstractMapDataStore.toObject(AbstractMapDataStore.java:78) ~[hazelcast-3.5.jar:3.5]
```

Comment: Apparently, the class `scala.colleciton.mutable.MutableList` is not in the classpath of the class loader which is used to deserialize your instance of class `Abc`.

Comment: i have added dependency for scala in my build.sbt file but it still gives me same eception , here is the dependcy for scala in my build.sbt   "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library-all" % "2.11.1"

Answer (score 1):

Your cluster must run with the same codebase (in this case the scala jar) as your clients.